# Split comma separated string ignore comma in single quotes and empty quotes

Tags: java

I want to split comma separated string ignoring single quotes. I know its a repeated question but it didn't help me. Below is line from file, I am trying to import SQl file which consists of columns values as follows:

line>>>>>
`127229,988,2,127247,'1',NULL,'/m','0',0,0,'0',NULL,NULL,'2015-02-16 06:59:37','2015-04-17 14:43:43','Resource Level','0',10523.52,0,0,10523.52,NULL,NULL,NULL,'color800000','','','N','969696',152,' ',NULL,0,0,0,',B,I`'

last column value must be `',B,I'` but with my code Its `'I'` only

I have used code

```
String[] temp = data.split(",(?=([^\']*\'[^\']*\')*[^\']*$)");
```

but unfortunately it didn't worked.

Comment: what you can do is replace all the single quotes by "" and then split the string on ","

Comment: i run your code and it's working :) but i remove "," before "("

Comment: Sorry my mistake :( Before that code executes there was some processing which was removing quotes from string, that is why It was not working.